# Django: database filter output displays <QuerySet [<model: model object (value)>]>

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am new to django, i am trying to import the data from a database by using multiple filters.

> views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import NodesdataArchive    
# Create your views here.
def home_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    data = NodesdataArchive.objects.filter(status=1, vendor='F5', location='NA')    
    host = {    
        "dns" : data 
    }
    return render (request, "home.html", {'posts': host})
```

After using multiple query i am selecting only the object "dns" to show. when i checked the value of the "host" variable its showing the right output. when i load it in the html template, its showing complete output which is shown in the "host" variable not the exact value alone.

current output :

> "QuerySet [NodesdataArchive: NodesdataArchive object (austin)>]>"

Expect output to show in the html template:

> austin

Please help, thanks !!!

models.py

`class NodesdataArchive(models.Model):
    ip_address = models.CharField(db_column='IP_Address', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    dns = models.CharField(db_column='DNS', max_length=255, blank=True, primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    vendor = models.CharField(db_column='Vendor', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    location = models.CharField(db_column='Location', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    status = models.CharField(db_column='Status', max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably in your template you've got

```
{{ dns }}
```

Try

```
{% for item in dns %}
   {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

Explanation:
You're downloading a queryset, not a specific item, because you're using `filter()`.  If you know that only one record will meet the filter criteria, use `NodesdataArchive.objects.get(status=1, vendor='F5', location='NA')` and then {{ dns  }} will work in the template.

Comment: i have the query from filter to get, if i mention {{ dns }} in the template nothing is displaying in the web page. if i mention {{ posts.dns }} its showing this time `NodesdataArchive object (austin)`. I have tried with the loop as well nothing is displaying.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read you post well enough.  Try `{{ posts.dns }}`.  This may require you to loop over it as illustrated before

Comment: if i use loop i get the error  **'NodesdataArchive' object is not iterable**, if i use without loop `{{ posts.dns }}`, i get the output as `NodesdataArchive object (austin)`

Comment: `{{ posts.dns.fieldname }}` where `fieldname` is what you want printed

Comment: i have founded the solution. for single value query = `NodesdataArchive.objects.get(status=1, vendor='F5', location='NA').dns` and for mutiple entry                                                                                               
       `for data in NodesdataArchive.objects.filter(status=1, vendor='F5', location='NA'):                                                                                                             print(data.dns) `                         Thanks for your help @HenryM